# using points to create lines

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, logic

Tom was given a total of $9$ candies plus an infinite number of lines and he need to place them such that it follows the following condition:

1) when connecting two candies with a line, there must be three candies on that line or we cannot place it;

2) a candy can be on different lines

Show the maximum number of lines that can be created following this rule. An image is provided below for having 5 points:
[image]
This is an extension problem from the KSEA 2018 grade 11 math exam (a finished math contest held on 4/7) , and I really struggled with this. First of all I started with small examples:

$3$ candy- $1$ lines

$4$ candy- $1$ line

$5$ candy- $2$ lines

$6$ candy- $4$ lines

Although I am pretty sure about these examples, I am really shaky to advance; I do not have a systematic method. One of my ideas is to argue by combinatorics; for each line generated, there will be a total of $3 \choose 2$ ways to connect two candies taken away. Then I tried this to disprove that 5 candies can generate 3 lines; but $5 \choose 2$- 3$3 \choose 2$ is not negative which shows my way doesnt work... I cannot really come up with a proper solution for this. Some suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe ask a related question: suppose you draw $n$ lines on a plane and see where they intersect. How many candies would you have to place on the plane to create that line drawing?

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand it-- can you explain a little more thoroughly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum number of lines $\mathcal{N}$ is $10$.

This number $10$ is achieved by following configuration:

[image: ten 3-point-lines through nine points]

This bounds $\mathcal{N}$ from below by $10$.

For an upper bound, let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be any set of $n \ge 3$ points in the plane and $L$ be the collection of lines containing at least 2 points from $S$.

Out of these $n$ points, we can form $\frac12 n(n-1)$ pairs from them. For any line in $L$, if it contains $m$ points from $S$, it will contain $\frac12 m(m-1)$ pairs. Notice a pair uniquely determine a line, this means the set of pairs associated with different lines in $L$ are disjoint. If we let $N_m$ be the number of lines containing $m$ points from $S$, we have:

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \sum_{m \ge 2} N_m \frac{m(m-1)}{2}\tag{*1}$$

This leads to 
$\quad\displaystyle\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \ge N_2 + 3 N_{\ge 3}\quad$ where $\quad N_{\ge 3} \stackrel{def}{=} \sum\limits_{m\ge 3} N_m$.
In $1958$, Kelly and Moser has shown$\color{blue}{{}^{[1]}}$:

> If $S$ doesn't lie on a single line, then $N_2 \ge \frac{3n}{7}$.

For the problem at hand, we have $n = 9$. Above result implies

$$N_{\ge 3} \le \frac13 \left(\frac{9(9-1)}{2} - \frac{3(9)}{7}\right) 
= \frac{75}{7}$$
Since LHS is an integer, we find
$N_{\ge 3} \le 10$ unless $S$ lies on a single line.
If $S$ lies on a single line, it is clear $N_{\ge 3} = 1$. Combine these, we can conclude out of any set $S$ of $9$ points, we can construct at most $10$ lines which passes through $3$ or more points from $S$.

This establishes the upper bound $\mathcal{N} \le 10$.
Combine with the lower bound, we conclude $\mathcal{N} = 10$.

The problem here is related to the [orchard-planting problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orchard-PlantingProblem.html) which asks how to plant $n$ trees so that there will be $r(n,k)$ straight rows with k trees in each row. The variant of finding the maximum number of $3$-point lines for $n$ points is due to Sylvester. Look at Borwein and Moser's survey article$\color{blue}{{}^{[2]}}$ for more info about the Sylvester problem. In particular, it has a proof of the Kelly and Moser's result mentioned above.

---

**Notes/References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - Kelly, L.M. and Moser, W. 1958. *On the number of ordinary lines determined by $n$ points*. Canad. J. Math. 10, 210-219. MR: 20, #3494.
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - Borwein, P & O. J. Moser, W. (1990). *A survey of Sylvester's problem and its generalizations*. Aequationes Mathematicae. 40. 111-135. 10.1007/BF02112289.

Comment: thank you very much-- this really do ease my confusion. Wonder if I could set this answer as protected with this exceptional quality.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Lower limit is at least 9]

Lower limit is at least 9, as seen here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an easy problem. Can the author maybe post or directly link to the question that inspired it from the KSEA 2018 exam? I took a quick look at example problems from  that exam but didn't find it.

Some thougths on the problem with 9 candies:

1) If you use a $3 \times 3$ grid pattern, you can find 8 lines with 3 candies on it, so the number of lines that can be placed is at least 8.

2) You can place at most 12 lines. One can see this as follows: Each candy can be part of at most 4 lines, because each such line must contain 2 other candies, but those 'other candies' can never be the same between different lines (if they were, the lines would be identical, as 2 different points determine a line already). That would mean at most $4\times 9 = 36$ lines, but as each line is counted at least three times this way (for the at least 3 candies on it), this boils down to at most 12 lines.

Comment: Oh this is quite similar to a line segment problem and there are only 6 candies in that exam, which is quite easy. However I just want to find a "solution" to this problem instead of guessing so I increased the number of candies to make this harder

Comment: I checked and the exam committee doesn't seem to release the problems yet-- I wonder if they will ever do

Comment: There are lots of mathematical problems that have a 'tractable' solution for small values of some variable, but cannot be solved generally. For 9 candies it still seems doable with using combinatorial methods: If you consider the candies a given base set $C$ with cardinality $n$, and consider the lines a set  $L$ of subsets of $C$, then we have $|l| \ge 3$ for each $l \in L$ (each placed line contains at least 3 candies) and $|l \cap g| \le 1$ for all different $l,g \in L$ (if lines contain the same 2 points (candies), they must be the same). This is a weakened version of the geometry problem.

Comment: This is only  weakend version of the real prioblem, as you may not be able to find actual points in the plane that create the lines you want to create. but it might give a better upper than the maximum of 12 lines.

Comment: Does that mean that we can always reach the maximum(upper bound) or does that only give a crude estimate of what the upper bound is? Thank you--

Comment: There is a number you are looking for. I showed that for 9 candies that number lies between 8 and 12 (inclusive), so 12 is an upper bound. Using the combinatorial idea I outlined above, it may be possible to get another upper bound. I hope that that this new upper bound is lower than 12 (otherwise it is of no use). But it still an upper bound, and not some approximation of an upper bound.